# Beamer - Show notes on second screen with customized section page using tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, beamer, pgfpages

I have recently built a custom beamer theme using tikz and wanted to add notes to my slides. Without notes it looked like this:

[image: Without Notes]

After inserting

```
\usepackage{pgfpages}
\setbeameroption{show notes on second screen}
```

it looked like this:

[image: With Notes]

I prepared a small example

```
\documentclass[aspectratio=169]{beamer}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{backgrounds}

\usepackage{pgfpages}
\setbeameroption{show notes on second screen}

% Colors
\definecolor{green}{RGB}{0,152,152}
\definecolor{gray}{RGB}{128,128,128}

% Define section page layout
\setbeamercolor{section}{fg=white}
\setbeamercolor{subsection}{fg=gray}
\setbeamertemplate{section page}%
{
  \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay, show background rectangle, background rectangle/.style={fill=gray}]
      \draw[green, fill=green]
        (-1,0.375) rectangle (13.66,-1.25);
      \node[text width=14.21cm, minimum width=14.66cm, minimum height=1.625cm, anchor=south west]
        at (-1, -1.25)
        {
          \begin{beamercolorbox}[right]{section}
            \usebeamerfont{title}\insertsection
          \end{beamercolorbox}                                                                                                                                             
        };
      \draw[lightgray, fill=lightgray] (2.2,-1.335) rectangle (13.66, -2.2);
      \node[text width=11.01cm, minimum width=11.46cm, minimum height=0.865cm, anchor=north west]
        at (2.2,-1.335)
        {
          \begin{beamercolorbox}[right]{subsection}
            \usebeamerfont{author}\insertsubsection
          \end{beamercolorbox}
        };
    \end{tikzpicture}
}

\begin{document}

\section{Some section}
\subsection{Some subsection}
\begin{frame}[plain]
  \sectionpage
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

I have really no idea what happened here. I compiled it with pdflatex but latex -> dvips -> ps2pdf, xelatex und lualatex produce the same output. The text is still there, you can copy and paste it. It looks like the background moved itself to the foreground...

Does anybody have an idea how to solve this problem?

Comment: It seems like the `background` library is not compatible with `pgfpages`. Not surprising because both involve post-processing the picture. What you can do is, since you are using `remember picture,overlay` already, you just draw a ridiculously big rectangle as background. Or you use beamer's protocol to set bg color. At least I saw what you expected when I remove `show background .......`

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion.
Adding `\draw[gray, fill=gray] (current bounding box.north west) rectangle (current bounding box.south east);` as first command within the tikzpicture environment yields to the same result.
Changing the beamer color for background canvas by simply using `\setbeamercolor{background canvas}{bg=gray}` works. However, all frames have a gray background and I want only the section page to have a gray background. I have not found a solution applying this change only to the section page.

Comment: Can you set `\setbeamercolor{background canvas}{bg=white}` back after the section page? It's verbose I know. But at least get it to work.

Comment: I don't know what `current bounding box` means in this situation. `\fill[yellow](current page.south west)rectangle(current page.north east);` would make more sense

Comment: Interestingly with `\fill[gray](current page.south west)rectangle(current page.north east);` it works. Would be the preferred solution.

Comment: If that solves your problem, you can answer your own question now, in a way that helps future visitors.

Comment: This problem is now solved in `beamer`'s development version.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using

```
\usetikzlibrary{backgrounds}
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay, show background rectangle, background rectangle/.style={fill=gray}]
```

with

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]
\fill[gray](current page.south west)rectangle(current page.north east);
```

the problem does not occur.

Answer (score 0):

This has been fixed in https://github.com/josephwright/beamer/commit/2e0b09acb735abf0b45856534bd5ff8c01bf7a5d

Please update to beamer v3.58 or newer.